# Apache Sling Resource Resolver

Tags: java, jackrabbit, sling

What exactly is the ResourceResolver? More important, how do you use it? I'm struggling to find a simple example. So, say I have a path and want to use the resource resolver to see if the path resolves to a resource. How would I do that? I know this is wrong but if someone can correct this it would help.

```
Iterator<String> nodeSample = getResource("title");
return nodeSample
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RequestResolver`, to quote the [javadoc](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html), defines the service API which may be used to resolve `Resource` objects.

You typically access it in a `SlingServlet` by calling `request.getResourceResolver()` or in a script ( JSP script for instance ) under the `resourceResolver` variable. For more details on variables on scripts see [Scripting variables in the Sling wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/SLING/scripting-variables.html).

One you get a hold of it you can use it to access resources in the content tree:

```
Resource resource = requestResolver.getResource("/content/my/resource");
if ( resource != null ) // bingo!
```

To display a resource's properties I usually adapt it to a `ValueMap` and then extract the properties

```
ValueMap properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
String title = properties.get("jcr:title", String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry but I'm still confused once you have access to the resource how would you display something related to a resource in the content tree. Would you do something like resource.getProperties('').  Again complete and I stress complete newb to this.